# How to align caption with table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Test test test test test}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
$V_{a}$ & $B$ & $r$ & $e/m$\\
(V) & (T) & (m) & (C/kg)\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
1 $\pm$ 1 & 2.04 $\pm$ 0.04 & 2.36 $\pm$ 0.1 & 1 $\pm$ 1\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to keep the formating of the table above how it is. It is the caption that I'd like to change. I don't like how it seems to be hanging off the right side of the table. I think the caption should be aligned with the left side of the table. How would I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Add to your preamble `\usepackage{caption} \captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false}`.

Comment: Otherwise, you can center the table adding `\centering` just after `\begin{table}` (probably this way it looks better inside a document).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `caption` package und use the `singlelinecheck=false` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
singlelinecheck=false % <-- important
]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Test test test test test}
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
$V_{a}$ & $B$ & $r$ & $e/m$\\
(V) & (T) & (m) & (C/kg)\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
1 $\pm$ 1 & 2.04 $\pm$ 0.04 & 2.36 $\pm$ 0.1 & 1 $\pm$ 1\\
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Explanation from the package documentation:

> The standard LATEX document classes (article, report, and book) automatically center a
>   caption if it ﬁts in one single line:

[image]

Comment: Wasn't this already in my comment?

Comment: @karlkoeller: Oh yes sorry - didn't see it. But it's a bit more than in the comment though.

Comment: I'm the first to give you more 10k :-) My best wishes. Hi.

Comment: @Sebastiano much appreciated!

Comment: This didn't work for me with RevTeX-4.1 in LyX :'(

Comment: What worked for me in the end was `\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}` and `\captionsetup{skip=0pt,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off}` thanks to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435579/14527). I may have something unnecessary from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427445/14527), but now that things are working I'm moving on with the project!