# How to align name of table to left?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions

Ok, so this is code:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{random123}
\label{name}
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
\hline 
test1 & test2\\
\hline
test3 & test4 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

And this is how it looks like and what I want to achieve:

[image: screen]

Any ideas how can I achieve similar result?

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: One way is to use the caption package with options singlelinecheck=false and possibly justification=raggedright.  Most people would center the tabular instead.

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136688/ solve your problem?