# text alignment in caption of table

Tags: tables, captions

I am trying make a caption at the bottom of the table but I want the text to continue under the Table number. Instead i get this:

[image]
and this is my code. Thank you!

```
\begin{table}
\centering
 \begin{threeparttable}
   
     \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}    ($\delta_i,c_i$)          & \textbf{low} $\boldsymbol{c_i}$} & \textbf{high} $\boldsymbol{c_i}$}                      \\ \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{high} $\boldsymbol{\delta_i}$}} & EU (13.8,54.8)              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}{*}{-}} \\
                                        & India (11.7, 65.8)           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                   \\
                                        & China (11.0, 18.8)           & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                   \\
                                        & US (10.6, 32.9)              & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}                   \\ \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{low} $\boldsymbol{\delta_i}$}}  & Russia (3.5, 93.9)         & Japan (2.4, 219.2 )                            \\
                                        & Brazil (2.9, 34.6)         & Canada (1.0, 328.8)                         \\
                                        &                  & S. Africa (0.7, 328.8)                        \\ 
                                       % \cmidrule(l){2-3}  
                                       \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item Source: \citet{holtsmark2020}, based on estimates from \citet{nordhaus2015climate} and Mclkinsey (2009).  \\
 \caption{ A high $\delta_i$ implies high marginal damages from emissions while a high $c_i$ implies high marginal abatement costs (for any given level of abatement) and for our model specification $c_i=1/\phi_i$.}
      
      
       \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please expand your sample code to a complete document, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. The way how the caption is formatted depends on the document class and the packages in the preamble.

Comment: Also check whether other postings here solve your problem, like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3176/how-can-i-left-align-a-caption or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136688/how-to-align-caption-with-table/136689

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also not sure, how you like to have formated captions. For example as:

[image]

In this case your MWE, using `threeparttablex` and clean-up all not needed `multicolumn`s can be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small, labelfont = {bf, sf}, 
              singlelinecheck=false}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
 \begin{threeparttable}
     \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \toprule
($\delta_i,c_i$) & \textbf{low} $\boldsymbol{c_i}$ & \textbf{high} $\boldsymbol{c_i}$ \\ 
        \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{high} $\boldsymbol{\delta_i}$} 
    & EU (13.8,54.8)        &  \multirow{4}{*}{---}     \\
    & India (11.7, 65.8)    &                           \\
    & China (11.0, 18.8)    &                           \\
    & US (10.6, 32.9)       &                           \\
        \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{low} $\boldsymbol{\delta_i}$} 
    & Russia (3.5, 93.9)    & Japan (2.4, 219.2 )       \\
    & Brazil (2.9, 34.6)    & Canada (1.0, 328.8)       \\
    &                       & S. Africa (0.7, 328.8)    \\
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, online]\footnotesize
    \source{Holtsmark and Weitzman (2020), based on estimates from Nordhaus(2015) and Mclkinsey (2009).}
      \end{tablenotes}
 \caption{ A high $\delta_i$ implies high marginal damages from emissions while a high $c_i$ implies high marginal abatement costs (for any given level of abatement) and for our model specification $c_i=1/\phi_i$.}
 \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i wanted to do with the caption, i think i just had to change the document class to article and then it worked. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood perfectly what you want, but is it something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\captionsetup{labelfont = {bf, sf}, indention=1cm}
 \begin{threeparttable}
     \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} ($\delta_i,c_i$) & \textbf{low} $\boldsymbol{c_i}$ & \textbf{high} $\boldsymbol{c_i}$ \\ \midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{high} $\boldsymbol{\delta_i}$} & EU (13.8,54.8) & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{4}{*}{---}} \\
                                        & India (11.7, 65.8) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
                                        & China (11.0, 18.8) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\
                                        & US (10.6, 32.9) & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} \\ \midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{low} $\boldsymbol{\delta_i}$} & Russia (3.5, 93.9) & Japan (2.4, 219.2 ) \\
                                        & Brazil (2.9, 34.6) & Canada (1.0, 328.8) \\
                                        & & S. Africa (0.7, 328.8) \\
                                       % \cmidrule(l){2-3}
                                       \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft, online]
      \small
      \item[Source:] Holtsmark and Weitzman (2020), based on estimates from Nordhaus(2015) and Mclkinsey (2009).
      \end{tablenotes}
 \caption{ A high $\delta_i$ implies high marginal damages from emissions while a high $c_i$ implies high marginal abatement costs (for any given level of abatement) and for our model specification $c_i=1/\phi_i$.}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]